# Pandas unit testing: How to assert equality of NaT and NaN values?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pandas, numpy, nan

In NumPy and Pandas, `nan != nan` and `NaT != NaT`. So, when comparing results during unit testing, how can I assert that a returned value is one of those values? A simple `assertEqual` naturally fails, even if I use `pandas.util.testing`.

Comment: use [`isnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.isnull.html#pandas.isnull)

Comment: simply `value != value` should be true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before doing an assert_frame_equal check, you could use the [.fillna() method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) on the dataframes to replace the null values with something else that won't otherwise appear in your values. You may also want to read [these examples](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html) on how to use the .fillna() method.

Comment: Thank you, this is almost exactly what I have been looking for. I'm saying "almost" as you can't pass `None`, which would be ideal as a type-neutral value, but another unique scalar, such as a zero or a string (e.g. `"INCORRECT!!!1!1!"` ;-) ), is good enough for now.

Comment: @BerislavLopac: perhaps I've misunderstood exactly what you're trying to do, but `assert_frame_equal` already asserts that `NaN` is equal to `NaN`. Using `fillna()` to replace `NaN` with some other scalar to be compared for equality is redundant and so isn't used in Pandas' unit tests.

Comment: Gah, you're right -- I took your advice too literally and called `fillna` _before_ `assert_frame_check`, so I missed that it works out the differences. Thanks!

Comment: @Alex, to improve on your answer, you can easily force a "something else that won't otherwise appear in your values" by using obejct(). If you define a variable and assign object() to it, and then use this variable in both the fillna method and the AssertEqual method - this solves the original question plus ensures your comparison for nan did not accidently catch also other cases.

Answer (score 7):

If you're comparing scalars, one way is to use `assertTrue` with `isnull`. For example, in the DataFrame unit tests (`pandas/tests/test_frame.py`) you can find [tests such as this](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/tests/frame/test_indexing.py#L1429-Lundefined):

```
self.assertTrue(com.isnull(df.ix['c', 'timestamp']))
```

(`com` is an alias for `pandas/core/common.py` and so `com.isnull` calls the same underlying function as `pd.isnull`.)

If on the other hand you're comparing Series or DataFrames with null values for equality, these are handled automatically by `tm.assert_series_equal` and `tm.assert_frame_equal`. For example:

```
>>> import pandas.util.testing as tm
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, np.nan]})
>>> df
    a
0   1
1 NaN
```

Normally, `NaN` is not equal to `NaN`:

```
>>> df == df
       a
0   True
1  False
```

But `assert_frame_equal` processes `NaN` as being equal to itself:

```
>>> tm.assert_frame_equal(df, df)
# no AssertionError raised
```

Answer (score 3):

Testing on python2.7, I get the following

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

x = np.nan
x is np.nan #True
x is pd.NaT #False
np.isnan(x) #True
pd.isnull(x) #True

y = pd.NaT
y is np.nan #False
y is pd.NaT #True
np.isnan(y) #TypeError !!
pd.isnull(y) #True
```

You can also use

```
x != x #True for nan
y != y #True for NaT
```

But I don't really like this style, I can never quite convince myself to trust it.