# How to get the same dict from a Pandas.DataFrame.to_dict when it has `nan`?

Tags: python, pandas, nan

I have a Pandas DataFrame constructed from a dict with a nan (e.g.: `float("nan")`). When I use `.to_dict` on it, I get a different dict - the nan values is something "else".

Is it possible to know what this new nan value is?

Here is a toy example I created, and a bunch of checks I did:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

a_dict = {
            "a": (1, 2),
            "b": (3, float("nan")),
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(a_dict)

print(df.to_dict())
# {'a': {0: 1, 1: 2}, 'b': {0: 3.0, 1: nan}}

# to_dict() gives a different dict:
print(a_dict == a_dict) # True
print(df.to_dict == a_dict)  # False

print(df.to_dict()["b"][1]) # nan
print(type(df.to_dict()["b"][1])) # <class 'float'>


print(df.to_dict()["b"][1] == float("nan"))  # False
print(df.to_dict()["b"][1] == np.nan)  # False
print(df.to_dict()["b"][1] == pd.NA)  # False
print(df.to_dict()["b"][1] is None)  # False
print(np.isnan(df.to_dict()["b"][1]))  # True
print(pd.isna(df.to_dict()["b"][1]))  # True
```

In terms of motivation, this is biting me when I try to create tests using `unittest.TestCase.assertEqual`

Thanks upfront.

Related but didn't help:

- [How can I check for NaN values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944700/how-can-i-check-for-nan-values)
- [Pandas unit testing: How to assert equality of NaT and NaN values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32524084/pandas-unit-testing-how-to-assert-equality-of-nat-and-nan-values)

Comment: This seems to be just because of `float('nan') != float('nan')`.

Comment: To get original dict `df.to_dict('list')` might help

Comment: Also if using np.nan then instead of checking `np.nan == np.nan #False` you can check `np.nan in (np.nan,) #True`

Comment: `float('nan') != float('nan')` mind blown :O

Answer (score 1):

As you stated to_dict() gives a different dict, but it is not related to the `nan` value.
`df.to_dict()` yields `{'a': {0: 1, 1: 2}, 'b': {0: 3.0, 1: nan}}` and not `{'a': (1, 2), 'b': (3, nan)}`, so it is not equal.
Replace the `nan` in `a_dict` with a number (e.g. `4`) and `df.to_dict == a_dict` will still evaluate to `False`, so the `nan` is not your problem.

I would like to point out that `np.nan == np.nan` evaluates to `False`. The fact that `a_dict == a_dict` evaluates to `True` is due to the definition of 'equal': Equal means that both dictionaries have the same keys and the keys refer to the same object or if the are equal.
See [here](http://www.lukelee.me/blog/posts/NaN-comparison-and-dictionaries) for more info.

To solve your initial question "How to get the same dict from a Pandas.DataFrame.to_dict?" see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62538305/convert-pandas-series-to-dictionary-without-index). It is a pain with the tuples you have in your dict and pandas automatically setting the datatype, which makes the code below fail.

<s>Basically you could do</s>

```
d = df.to_dict('list')
{i: tuple(d[i]) for i in d.keys()} == a_dict # True
```

Answer (score 1):

May be not the best way but this is how you can check for testing only

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

class custom_dict(dict):
    def __eq__(self, __o: object) -> bool:
        if isinstance(__o, dict):
            return self.keys() == __o.keys() and all(list(self[k1]) in (list(__o[k1]),) for k1 in self.keys())
        return False

a_dict = {
            "a": (1, 2),
            "b": (3, np.nan),
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(a_dict, dtype=object)
print(df.to_dict('list',into=custom_dict))
print(a_dict)
print(df.to_dict('list', into=custom_dict)["b"][1] in  (np.nan, )) # true
print(df.to_dict('list', into=custom_dict) == a_dict). # true
```

Comment: Looks cool!
why do we need:
```
from collections import defaultdict
from functools import partial
```
?

Comment: We do not need these modules, i was doing my own testing. Let me remove them.